# My code can't put data i input in my txt file, idk where i did wrong

Tags: c, file

```
      struct info
    {
    char code[4];
    char name[30];
    int quantity[3];
    float price[6];
    };
    void main()
    {
    FILE *f;
    int i,n,check;
    struct info ip;
    do
    {
    printf("How many products are about to input ?\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    check=scanf("%d",&n);
    if (check!=1) printf("Input again\n");
    }
    while (check!=1);
    f=fopen("products.txt","w");
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
    printf("Input product code\n");
    gets(ip.code);
    fputs(ip.code,f);
    printf("Input product name\n");
    gets(ip.name);
    fputs(ip.name,f);
    printf("Input product quantity\n");
    scanf("%d",&ip.quantity);
    fprintf(f,"%d",&ip.quantity);
    printf("Input product price\n");
    scanf("%f",&ip.price);
    fprintf(f,"%f",ip.price);
    }
    }
```

i can't manage to make user input from keyboard and write down in my txt file, can anyone help me where i'm wrong, and help me with a sample if the whole thing is wrong.

Comment: Could you please manage to re-format/indent it atleast ?

Comment: What input do you provide?  What output does this generate?  What output did you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Whoa! Never use `gets()`, and especially never with such tiny buffers as four characters.

Your problem is very likely to be a buffer overrun.

Use `fgets()` instead of `gets()` to read the strings, it will be much safer. Even better is to `fgets()` into a temporary line-buffer that is "large enough" (say 128 characters), and then you add code to inspect and extract the desired value from that and storing it in the `ip` fields. This also gives you a chance to validate the inputs.